# Welcome discount limited to time and membership group

Tags: expresso-store, discounts

For the moment when people signing up on new membership the system send out a welcome email with discount % to be used at our store limited to the membership group (Restrict to Member Groups) and limited to one purchase per customer (Limit Per Customer).

The down side is this discount code has unlimited time. I'm not sure if there is an already builtin feature to set how long this discount should last since member signed up (example 14 days) or if this is a feature request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Store that would allow you to do this. You would need to write an extension to check the members registration date against the coupon code.